# Confidence intervals for multiple output values of a Markov process using covariance?

Tags: confidence-interval, covariance

I have a Markov process (specifically the Wang-Landau algorithm) that produces a set of "weights" $w_i$ for $i=1,2,...,N$. The weights by themselves are actually meaningless, and what is actually being measured/encoded in this information is their ratios $w_i/w_j$. For computational purposes, we prefer to use the logs of the weights, so I'm actually working with $\ln(w_i)-\ln(w_j)$.

Let $v_i = \ln(w_i)-\ln(w_1)$. Now the set of $v_i$'s encodes the same information (their differences are the same as the differences between the logs of the original weights). And using $v_i$ lets us compare a given set of weights to another run of the Markov process.

Suppose I have $k$ replications of this experiment. I would like to produce confidence intervals for each $v_i$, and my first instinct was to use the variance of $v_i$ across the $k$ experiments. A collaborator is insisting that I should also be using the covariance in some way to calculate these confidence intervals.

How would I do this? I can't seem to find any sources that do this, and I don't quite see how this is necessary.